# C#, how to get the content of a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping

I'm new to c#. I need to do a script to get the HTML content of a webpage. Where I can get examples on how to do this? I have searched here but I can't find.

PS: Sorry for my dab english.

Best Regards,

Comment: You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: Check example section on [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method

Comment: Code Project has a [nice tutorial with sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/weather.aspx) on this.

Comment: look at [this Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `WebClient` class. The `DownloadString` method returns a content of a page as a string:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var html = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

If you also want to parse the downloaded HTML, then you can take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net). It allows you to parse the HTML into a tree-like structure (similar to `XmlDocument`) and you can use XPath to find elements in the document etc. It is much better approach then using regular expressions or parsing the content yourself.